# CodeIgniter 2 not allowing multiple level subfolders for controllers

Tags: codeigniter

As I read the [doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/controllers.html), controllers in CodeIgniter are supposed to support multiple level subfolders, but as far as I have tested, it is impossible to work after first a first level folder.

By example:

`mysite.dev/` (index page, default controller home.php, works)

`mysite.dev/admin/` (admin section, in admin/home.php, works)

`mysite.dev/admin/manage/` (in admin/manage/home.php, do not work)

I am trying to know why and how to make it work on multiple level sub folders?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using a route to point to the controller 2 levels deep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CI only allows one sub-dir level. However, you can emulate this pattern with routes file as @Brendan says:

Controllers:

```
welcome.php
admin/admin.php
admin/manage.php
```

Routes file:

```
$route['admin/manage/:any'] = "admin/manage/$1";
$route['admin/admin'] = 'admin/home.php';
```

You can implement some changes to the hardcode to get works as expected: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/190563/

Comment: Is there a way to make it automatic? Like I won't have to add every route for every seconth-level controller?

Comment: CI does in fact support subdirectories for controllers.

Comment: @WesleyMurch, yep, it does, but one subdir level

Comment: Ah I see, looks like you're right (and I misread your comment about that).