# CodeIgniter controller in subfolder

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a controller in a subfolder. CodeIgniter is giving a 404 page not found.

The controller works fine in the root controller folder. The controller also works fine in the 1st level subfolder. The controller breaks in the 2nd level subfolder.

Why would CodeIgniter **not** want you to user multiple subfolders?

**Example:**

Works: `controllers/pages/HomeController.php`

Broken: `controllers/pages/users/HomeController.php`

My Routes are like this:

Works: `$route['default_controller'] = "pages/HomeController";`

Broken: `$route['default_controller'] = "pages/users/HomeController";`

Comment: Found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240111/codeigniter-2-not-allowing-multiple-level-subfolders-for-controllers

Seems dumb that CI only lets you go 1 level down.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote about this before, you just need to read the CI manual, but here is a quick blog entry I did which should get you back on track:

http://blog.biernacki.ca/2011/12/codeigniter-uri-routing-issue-with-controller-folders/

**Example:**

```
$route['account/manage/(:num)/(:any)']  = "account/manage/index/$1/$2";
```

Comment: I read your post, and I'm not clear what you are naming your actual controller object. Is it "Manage"? And then in Manage you just manually reroute to the controller you want?

Comment: And why does CI not allow multiple level subfolders?

Comment: controller is called `manage` it is right there in the post...? there is nothing that it 'doesn't allow' it just needs to be routed properly as the default is `controller/method/values`, the example above is `folder/controller/method(index)/value/value` (right hand side)

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter does not inherently allow for multiple controller folders. It may or may not work, but it is an undocumented quirk. Using the routes.php file you can virtualize any folder or controller structure you want, just take care to map your routes back to a controller and method in the Controllers folder.